# Мусор при сортировке

Tags: c++, сортировка

После сортировки в массиве NxN появляется мусор, с каждым разом мусор в разных местах.

Помогите решить проблему.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void siftDown(int *numbers, int root, int bottom)       //формирование кучи
{
    int maxChild;                                       //индекс максимального потомка
    int done = 0;                                       //флаг, куча сформирована

    while ((root * 2 <= bottom) && (!done))             //пока не дошли до последнего ряда
    {
        if (root * 2 == bottom)                         //если мы в последнем ряду, 
            maxChild = root * 2;                        //запоминаем левый потомок

        else if (numbers[root * 2] > numbers[root * 2 + 1])     //иначе запоминаем больший потомок из двух
            maxChild = root * 2;
        else
            maxChild = root * 2 + 1;

        if (numbers[root] < numbers[maxChild])                  //если элемент вершины меньше максимального потомка
        {
            int temp = numbers[root];                           //меняем их местами
            numbers[root] = numbers[maxChild];
            numbers[maxChild] = temp;
            root = maxChild;
        }
        else 
            done = 1;                                           //пирамида сформирована
    }
}

void heapSort(int *numbers, int array_size)                     //сортировка
{

    for (int i = (array_size / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)             //нижний ряд пирамиды
        siftDown(numbers, i, array_size);

    for (int i = array_size - 1; i >= 1; i--)                   //просеиваем через пирамиду остальные элементы
    {
        int temp = numbers[0];
        numbers[0] = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = temp;
        siftDown(numbers, 0, i - 1);
    }
}

int main() {

    int size;
    int R, C;
    int tempp[50];
    char *str = new char[30];

    ifstream inn("dann.txt");
    while (!inn.eof()) {                            //подсчет размера массива NxN

        inn.getline(str, '\n');
        size++;
        R = size;

    }


        //inn.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
        inn.close();

        inn.open("dann.txt");

        int **arr = new int* [R];                   //создание динамического двумерного массива
        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[R];
        }

        while (!inn.eof()) {                        //заполнение массива из файла   

            for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <R; j++) {
                    inn >> arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {               //вывод массива без сортировки
            for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
                cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {           //временное хранение столбца
            tempp[i] = arr[i][0];
        }

        heapSort(tempp, R);                     //вызов сортировки

        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
            arr[i][0] = tempp[i]; 
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {               //вывод массива
            for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
                cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {               //очистка памяти от масива 
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;


inn.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ерунды в коде много, но что касается мусорных значений, то вот это ветвление в `siftDown`

```
    if (root * 2 == bottom)
        maxChild = root * 2;
    else if (numbers[root * 2] > numbers[root * 2 + 1])
        maxChild = root * 2;
    else
        maxChild = root * 2 + 1;
```

это какая-то белиберда. Величина `bottom` изначально - это размер массива. Поэтому по индексу `bottom` в массив доступаться нельзя - там в лучшем случае сидит мусор. У вас же запросто может получиться, что `maxChild` станет равно `bottom`, а потом мусор из `numbers[maxChild]` запросто может затянуться внутрь массива.

Равенство `root * 2 == bottom` говорит о том, что у узла вообще нет сыновей. В условии цикла сравнение должно быть строгим

```
while (root * 2 < bottom && !done)
```

и т.д.